# How do I build custom Ubuntu CD's automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, distribution-media

I'd like to build custom Ubuntu installation CD's daily (CRON job). Think [Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/) but with custom packages coming from a text file. Packages would be a mix of some official Ubuntu packages as well as some custom packages from other sources.

Any help would be appreciated but I'm specifically looking for suggestions on what tools/software I could use to get this done. Less software = better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like cdimage (which is what creates the Daily Build, and other Ubuntu images).  You can read more about it and how to configure it here:

http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/bzr/cdimage/mainline/README

Comment: Great, thank you! Most probably I will end up dissecting scripts from cdimage to make it work exactly like I need it.